# SaveChanges method is not inserting data into database, however works while deleting

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
EmployeeDbContex contex = new EmployeeDbContex();

tbl_Employee Employee = new tbl_Employee();
Employee.Name = txtname.Text.Trim();
Employee.Address = txtAddress.Text.Trim();
Employee.Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalary.Text.Trim());
Employee.Gender = ddGender.SelectedItem.Text;
Employee.ContactNo = txtContact.Text.Trim();

contex.tbl_Employee.Add(Employee);

contex.SaveChanges();
```

The `SaveChanges()` method in the above code is not working. The values are assigned to properties but changes are not made in database while inserting new data.

However, when I perform deletion it works perfectly. When I checked the program in debug mode the control just passes through the `SaveChanges()` method and does not jump to definition of this method.

Comment: Please add more code to show your database set up and delete function. Also do you get any errors?

Comment: You aren't implementing `Using` keyword, so your `tbl_Employee` may be detached? Does an exception occur?